# Cannot change predefined String value

Tags: java, android

I am building an audio recorder app. To store created audio files i create them using this String to name them

```
`public String inputName = "recorded_audio";`
```

this is the defult audio clip name unless the user types an other one by using `nameBtn`

Later i use an other String for the final name of the file

```
`mediaFileName += "/Files/Recordings/" + inputName + ".mp3";`
```

I want to give the user the option to name their files instead of having that "recorded_audio.mp3" so i added a button that pops up a dialogue for the user to insert a value. When pressed ok, the String `inputName` should have its value replaced by the user's input, so the next time a recording happens, the file will be saved with the user's input as a name. The problem: No matter what user inputs the files are always saved with the initial value of the String, as if the user never inputted a value.

```
public String inputName = "recorded_audio";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio_recorder);

    recordBtn = findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
    nameBtn = findViewById(R.id.nameBtn);
```

The dialog pop-up:

```
    nameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = (LayoutInflater.from(AudioRecorder.this)).inflate(R.layout.audio_name_input, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AudioRecorder.this);
            alertBuilder.setView(view);
            final EditText userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.userInput);

            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
                }

            });

            Dialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Saving the file:

```
    String folder_main = "Files/Recordings"; //Creates folder path
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
    file.mkdirs();
    mediaFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mediaFileName += "/Files/Recordings/" + inputName + ".mp3";
```

Record Button:

```
    recordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                    //User stops touching the button
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (isRecording) {
                            stopRecording();

                            File file = new File(mediaFileName);
                            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
                            if(file_size >= 4096) {
                                finish(); //Finishes activity.
                                startActivity(getIntent()); //Restarts activity in order to reset chronometer
                                startActivity(new Intent(AudioRecorder.this, AudioPlayer.class)); //Once recording is complete loads AudioPlayer activity
                            }
                            isRecording = false;
                        }
                        break;

                    //User touches the button
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //Recording Proccess
                        isRecording = true;
                        }
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: have you tried calling ````userInput.getText().toString()```` instead ?

Comment: Didn't work @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0):

This should go without saying, but have you tried putting a breakpoint on this line?:

```
inputName = String.valueOf(userInput.getText());
```

You need to verify that this code is even getting called.  And you should watch the value of inputName before and after executing the statement.  As @a_local_nobody said, your syntax is incorrect and wouldn't give you what you want anyway, however, it shouldn't leave inputName unaltered (unless the String.valueOf was throwing an error that you are not catching, which is possible). Setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code execution will show you exactly what is happening. This is what your syntax should look like:

```
inputName = userInput.getText().toString();
```

You also need to check that the EditText userInput is, in fact, instantiated, and not a null value.,